# Do I need to extend ClassLoader to redirect web application resource loading?

Tags: java, web-applications, classloader

My question is two-fold.  First, I'll explain the problem, and second, assuming the solution is to implement a class loader, how to go about doing that on a web application.

My problem is this:  Our company is using a framework made by another company.  It uses xml files to generate web pages and these xml files are located within another library (jar files).  It wasn't meant to be dynamic because these libraries are generated often (weekly?), but they determine how many fields there are, what type of information it collects (datetime, combo box, etc.), and so on.

Now the question has been proposed by my company whether or not it would be possible to dynamically move these fields around (by dynamic, I mean ideally you could refresh the page and see the effects of changes made to the layout).  I did a few preliminary tests and discovered that modifying the xml does give the desired effect on the web page, however, since these xml files are located in the jars, it means I have two possibilities:

1. Create a tool which modifies the jar outside of the scope of my web application, though this would obviously imply that it absolutely cannot be dynamic.  Moreover, I'd have to create an interface aside from the web application in order to manage the tool.  Moreover still, I can't seem to shake the impression that this is an incredibly hacky approach and that I should probably avoid this solution at any cost.
2. I implement a class loader (specifically `getResourceAsStream`) and when I see a call to load one such xml file, rather than do the default behavior, I generate the xml file based on the original, modifying information as I require, then returning the resource to the caller (which in this case would be the third-party framework).

First question is, is #2 my best option or do there exist other options (or should I stick to #1)?

My second question is, assuming I should implement my own class loader, how best can I do this on my web application?  I'm using Tomcat 7, but if possible I would like the solution to be independent of which web container I'm using.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd first check if the framework can *only* load XML from the classpath. There might be other 'connectors' for filesystem loading, etc. If not, I'd see how easy it would be to modify the code to allow for other 'connectors'. If neither are possible, I think your idea is a promising one. I've dealt with frameworks that only offer 'classpath connectors' and they're **extremely** annoying!

Comment: I'm not familiar with connectors.  I'm not even 100% sure the xml files are being accessed using a class loader.  I just assumed that if it is located in the jar file that a class loader is being used.  Is there anyway to verify that connectors aren't being used?  Thanks for your reply, @PaulGrime!

Comment: Hi, I didn't mean anything specific by connectors, I just meant a connector as 'the code that is responsible for providing the xml content to the application'.

Comment: @PaulGrime It's possible that yes, there are better ways of doing this, but though we pay a pretty penny for support for this library, without a clear and concise question on the matter, it might take anywhere from 2 weeks to a month to get a solid answer out of them.  Even then, it's not guaranteed the answer is yes, that they support what we're trying to do.  For all intents and purposes, assume there's no other way of doing it.  If I get more information I'll share it here.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably simply explode the jar to a directory that is on the classpath and update the XML files in place and on the fly. This won't account for any internal caching within the application, (if any, that's a different problem) but it's straightforward to implement and doesn't put you in the shenanigan filled ClassLoader business.

Comment: I hadn't considered that, actually.  Wouldn't the web container go into a panic if it saw one of its classpath resources continually change?

Comment: I think you'll need to consider the classloader caching the XML, as well as any explicit application caching. Classloaders often cache the resources that are loaded through them. Therefore making changes to the XML files might not result in the classloader reloading them.

Comment: Classloaders tend to cache classses, and they do that indirectly (because they simply load them and use the VM as the "cache"). But for normal resources, while they can, they tend not too as is a bit presumptive for them to assume it cacheable content, or that you even want them cached. Obviously classloaders "can do anything". Caching makes a lot more sense for a network based loader than a file based loader, and you will have to test for yourself whether the classloader is going to behave as expected. But in my experience, they tend to leave non-class parts pretty well alone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question.But I guess you could try using xstream api from thoughtworks.It can generate xml on the fly for you given a Java object and from this point on you can treat these xmls the way you do now to generate your webpages.
I know this answer is very trivialising however if this can lead you to a new api that can help you move to a new approach of generating xml with minimum fuss then I guess it would have served your purpose well.

Comment: I understand where you're getting at, but my problem isn't so much the generation of the web pages as it is modifying the original xml.  I can't just "wing it" and make the xml from scratch, even if I could, but I can't because the third party library is doing it for me.